# What and how is the relationship between the United States of America plus the European Union on the African Union?

Tags: united-states, european-union, international-relations, foreign-policy, african-union

I've seen a photo of Ivanka Trump and H.E.AMB.Kwesi Quartey and I wanted to ask what the Relationship between the US and the African Union is as well as the European Union, as cooperation between both are strong and what each of their Interests are!

[image: Readout from Advisor to the President’s Meeting with African Union Deputy Chairperson Kwesi Quartey and Signing of Communique]

Comment: The relations between these three political entities are complex and their interests are wide. Can you be more specific about what you would like to know?